# How to send properties to self made events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

How to send properties to self made events?
I try something like this… Maybe exist is another structure to resolve this functions?

```
var mme=document.getElementById('mme');

mme.event1=function(prop){
 alert(prop.property);
}
mme.event2=function(prop){
 alert(prop.property);
}
////////
mme.eventN=function(prop){
 alert(prop.property);
}

$(mme).trigger('eventX',{property:'Hello World!'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you are wanting both events and methods.

```
// Native Method
mme.event1 = function(argument) {
    alert(argument);
};

// Native Event Handler
mme.onevent1 = function(event, argument) {
    alert(argument);
};

// jQuery Event Handler
$(mme).on("event1", function(event, argument) {
    alert(argument);
});
```

When you trigger an event, jQuery will call the jQuery Handler, the Native Handler, then the Native Method.  Only the handlers will have the parameters passed.  The native method is called without parameters.

From jQuery v1.9.1, line 3018:

```
elem[ type ]();
```

type is the name of the event.

This jsFiddle shows all 3 being called:
http://jsfiddle.net/nV8qg/2/

Comment: I've updated my answer with a DOM handler that is passed arguments

Comment: Very interesting, never would have thought to put the 'on' before the event

Answer (score 2):

You can do this -

```
$('#mme').on('event1', function (e) {
    console.log(e.hello);
});

var e = $.Event("event1", {
    hello: "Hello"
});

$('#mme').trigger(e);
```

Demo `------>` http://jsfiddle.net/fh2eC/

Comment: This is a good solution and I have used it before, but in this case, i can't do something like this ``mme.eventN({property:'Hello World!'})``